# MS Project 2010 / Excel Create: S curve and add forecast line based on Remaining work

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-project-2010

I can created an S curve in excel using planned / actual based on man hours and timescale from Project (task usage, BL hours and Actual hr fields )and put into excel. 
I am trying to find a way to use the remaining hours (after changing the status date and Updating Project) but there is no field for that in Task usage. I want to be able to transfer them to excel so that the remaining hours are showing in the timescale used for the S curve and then I can add a forecast line to my graph.

Probably very simple to Super users but I am struggling.

Regards
peter

Answer (score 0):

In the Task Usage field, scroll to the right in the table section and click on the last column header "Add New Column". Select "Remaining Work" to see work hours at the resource level and task level. Or select "Remaining Duration" to see the time left at the task level.